# Visual Studio, MSMQ and WCF debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, msmq

I am trying to debug within VS2010 a message which gets dispatched from my Transactional MSMQ by WCF.

I have 1 message on the queue.

The problem is that if I place a debug breakpoint and leave it for a good few seconds and I step to the next line, i see the message being redispatched again to the application causing the frame to jump back to the starting/entry point of the application again.

any ideas on how I can just get it to work with the 1 message? (there is only one message on the queue so my question is on how I can prevent it from dispatching multiple times)

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, setting the WCF service to InstanceContext.Single and Concurrency mode to single seems to work fine. It is a pain though since you have to switch between debugging and release and make sure to modify the app config or service itself to make it MT

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you are dealing with WCF timeouts here.

I believe that your service ends the session while you are debugging. Since the message was not fully processed in your debug session it then reads the message from the queue again and everthing restarts from the entry point.

You might want to try to set the timeouts for the bindings in you `Web.config` or `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` files to higher values:

```
<binding name="yourEndpointName" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                <!-- other config values here --> >
```

You have to increase (at least) the binding `receive timeout`, binding receive timeout is responsible for session time out.

Comment: That did not quite work sadly. it still caused the problem. Here is what I have: <bindings>
      <msmqIntegrationBinding>
        <binding name="IncomingMessageHandlerBinding" closeTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </msmqIntegrationBinding>
    </bindings>

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: Are you absolutely sure that the second message **is the same** message as the first one? Did you check the contents? Possibly you are reading from the queue in a **multi-threaded** way...?

Comment: Jens - there is only 1 message in the queue ever. it is the same message and yes, it is MT however if there is only 1 message in the queue then there is no reason to redispatch it so it seems to be some timeout related issue as you mentioned originally causing the redispatch to happen again.

Comment: ok, setting the WCF service to InstanceContext.Single and Concurrency mode to single seems to work fine. It is a pain though since you have to switch between debugging and release and make sure to modify the app config or service itself to make it MT

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, you can make use of the multiple config files, like Web.Debug.Config / Web.Release.Config that allow you to apply different configuration for different needs - just as in you case. You can even create unlimited arbitrary other configuration as you need it.

Comment: I agree and know you can but you cannot seem to configure the InstanceContextMode or even the Concurrency mode from the config at all :( it has to be either on the attribute itself or when constructing/initiating the service within code.

Comment: I also have to set receiveRetryCount=0 for this to work.